# Where to store images in Amazon AWS for use in RDS

Tags: image, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, storage

I am currently creating a bunch of tables on the MySQL service in Amazon RDS. Several of the tables need to have image links in them.  What I am trying to figure out, is where do I put the images?  Do they go in RDS somewhere?  or do i put them in S3 and link them to RDS? If the latter, how do I do that?

I have googled the heck out of this, with no conclusion so any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the image sizes, use cases, etc, I would probably store the images in S3.

You can store the S3 path as a database field. You can create a bucket as a domain name (ie, images.example.com), and point the CNAME to the bucket to get direct access to the images. You can also use the various S3 libraries to generate a time limited signed URL if you want to include security.

Answer (score 3):

You can either store them just as binary-data in a column in RDS or you can use S3. If you use S3 you store the http-url to the image in RDS and then get the image over http from S3.

Comment: Ok, I set up a bucket in S3 and uploaded an image, set the permissions and got the http link.  Then add the link to my table in RDS, like so:                                                                 INSERT INTO images_test
VALUES (NULL, 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/images_pregcompanion/dog.jpg');

Comment: I then wrote a php script to retrieve the image:                                                              <?php
 $dbhost = 'myinstance.cfnip3dcjkqj.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
 $dbuser = 'name';
 $dbpass = 'pass';
 $dbname = 'test';

// Connect to server and select database.
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbname)or die('cannot select DB');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images_test");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$content = $row['image'];

header('Content-type: image/jpg');
     echo $content;
?>

Comment: The response from the PHP script is' cant display the image because it contains errors.  I am able to click on the link in S3 and see the image.  Any ideas?

Comment: You need to fetch the image as well. From what I can see in your code you are only echoing the url of the image, not the contents of the image.